# Paypal Developer - Cant view my REST Apps

Tags: paypal

Getting the following error when clicking on an app.

"We’re sorry, but something went wrong while displaying view/edit page for application. Please try again."

Anyone have this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they are working on this right now
please be patient
i hope this issue is resolved until tomorrow

[image: link]
<sub>(source: [hmtk.com](http://www.hmtk.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/techsupportcat.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Where do we find service status info?

Comment: @Emad I have found the following service status page: https://www.paypal-notify.com//eventnotification/search?eventSearchType=PayPalSiteStatus

Comment: I still get it but on the status page it shows that the issue is resolved. anyone else still has the problem?

Comment: from a support representative in 1/29/2015: "There are still intermittent issues with Sandbox. I hope you continue to be able to access it, but we are experiencing issues for some merchants."

Comment: I am getting the same error as well today - "We’re sorry, but something went wrong while displaying view/edit page for application. Please try again."

Comment: just tested. problem still there.

Comment: Well, at least I am not only the one

Comment: it seems that it's up and running again

Comment: Working for me now too.